# ReactJS--My data returns empty with axios

Tags: reactjs

I am new in react.i want fetch data from database with axios.
my url is :

```
[{"id":1,"username":"elyash14","role":"admin","email":"a@gmail.com","f_name":"\u0627\u0644\u06cc\u0627\u0633","l_name":"\u0645\u0633\u06cc\u0628\u06cc","avatar":null,"phone":"09118060752","address":"rasht","gender":"female","national_code":"3216549870","active":1,"last_login":"2019-10-28 17:17:10","created_at":null,"updated_at":"2019-10-28 17:17:10"},{"id":2,"username":"mohsen007","role":"admin","email":"lotfimohsen007@gmail.com","f_name":"\u0645\u062d\u0633\u0646","l_name":"\u0644\u0637\u0641\u06cc","avatar":null,"phone":"09380151562","address":"rasht","gender":"male","national_code":"2580231307","active":1,"last_login":"2019-10-29 15:26:26","created_at":"2019-09-05 14:43:39","updated_at":"2019-10-29 15:26:26"}]
```

but when I am using axios data, it returns empty.here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';


class userList extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      users: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost/bank/public/api/users')
      .then(response => {
        const users = response.data;
        this.setState({ users });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.users.map(user => <li>{user.email}</li>)}
      </ul>
    )
  }

}

export default userList;
```

thanks for your answer

Comment: are you getting data from api in respone? console and check

Comment: code is working properly, you must check you api.

Comment: this is console:Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/bank/public/api/users' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
createError.js:17 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:80)

Comment: to resolve cors issue either install cors crome extension or allow from backend api.

Comment: @Moh3n007 here is a good video explaining [CORS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gwKTj2wddfE).

Comment: I did install cors chrome extension but Problem did not fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for your reference you can see this as an example.

Used different api - https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums

```
class userList extends React.Component{
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      users: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ users: response.data });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.users.map(user => <li>{user.title}</li>)}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: my api is same to your

Comment: @Moh3n007 but your api has issue of cors because your api is http instead of https.

Comment: oh...ok.how I fix it?with extension?

Comment: @Moh3n007 add this in your crome and enable https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

don't you miss port number like localhost:3000?

Comment: I didn't understand. Where?